# Hypocycloid with an outer ellipse

Tags: integration, trigonometry, conic-sections, parametric

I have tried to change the traditional hypocycloid a bit.  What I've basically done is that a circle now rolls inside an ellipse.  I am trying to find the equation for the same.  I am mostly done, except the last part.  Where I've to find $\phi$ in terms of $\theta$.  Could anyone please help me regarding this? 
[image]

Also, I would appreciate if somebody could post the whole answer, so that I can double check my steps.

Thanks a lot for your help :)

**P.S.:** Can we do this without elliptical integrals?  Because that's too complicated for my level.

Comment: It's mission impossible to do it without elliptic integrals in case of rolling without slipping.  By the way, it's doable for an ellipse rolling on a sine curve.

Comment: There's this: https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/ellipse-perimeter.html